# Делая бота столкнулся с ошибкой AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, telegram-bot, telebot

Делаю бота для отправки напоминаний. Столкнулся с тем что когда пытаюсь создать задачу в АТ вылетает ошибка **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'**.
Вот код:

```
def add_task(id, text, date_time, dt_text):  # Функция создают задачу в AT и добавляет ее в бд
    uid = uuid.uuid4()
    cmd = f"""echo "{sdir}/send_message.py {id}  \'{text}\' {uid} '' " | at {date_time}"""
    out = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    stdout = str(out.communicate())
    number = re.search('job(.+?) at', stdout).group(1)
    add_to_db_tasklist(id, number, dt_text, text, uid)
```

Comment: ну значит re.search() ничего не находит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) вернет `None`, если в переданной строке не удалось найти подстроку по шаблону регулярки.

Поэтому, проверяйте результат, например:

```
m = re.search('job(.+?) at', stdout)
if m:
    number = m.group(1)
    add_to_db_tasklist(id, number, dt_text, text, uid)
```